# What does a “successor” stand for in llvm?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

When I reading the llvm document, especially the `BasicBlock` part, the concept “successor” appears a lot, so what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both terms, `basic block` and `successor`, are coming from the field of [Control Flow Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_analysis) (or CFA).
In CFA, a program is represented using [Control Flow Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph) (or CFG).

Each vertex (or node) in a CFG is a basic block. Since CFG is a directed graph, a basic block may have incoming and outcoming edges. E.g.: A -> B -> C. Incoming edges are coming from predecessors, and the outcoming edges are leading to successors.

The set of successors/predecessors for the mentioned example (`A -> B -> C`):

```
pred(A) = {}
succ(A) = {B}

pred(B) = {A}
succ(B) = {C}

pred(C) = {B}
succ(C) = {}
```

Comment: So can I understand the successors as basic blocks which the current basic block can lead to?

Comment: yes that's correct. Also, to add to @AlexDenisov there can be multiple successors/predecessors in CFG when we have branch statements or loops

Answer (score 1):

A successor is the target of a the branch that ends a basic block.

For example, if a basic block ends with a five-way switch, then that block has six successors (five explicit and the switch's default). A basic block that ends with a return has no successors.

Comment: How about a if-else statement? Two successors?

Comment: Yes, precisely.